# Check form fields and insert value to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a simple php/html form wich inserts data to my mysql database.

I have a column on my database called **type**.
When a form is submitted with various values I want to be able to check the value of those submitted fields and add a value to the column type based on those values:
If the submitted form field **field1** has the value **value1** and field **field2** has the value **value2** then insert **value3** to column **type** on my database.

Comment: The question asked by you is not clear. Please explain it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage this with code, if I understand your question right. 
Remember, it is a good idea to check the post values, before insert or update some values in the database. 
I am using post for the form method, if you use get, replace $_POST with $_GET

```
<?php
if ($_POST["field1"] == "value1" AND $_POST["field2"] =="value2") 
{  $type = $value3
}
else
{  /// create some defaultvalue if the condition is not true. 
   $type = "youdefaultvalue" 
   // or you use some other value from your form, for example $_POST["field3"]
}
// here create your sql-action like "insert into ... " or update ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you need this exactly. But after reading your question, i hope you are looking like this only.

```
if($_POST['field1'] == "value1" && $_POST['field2'] == 'value2' ){

       // INSERT field3 to type
}
```